# Is it possible changeset is not associated to any of the component?

Tags: rtc, java, changeset, rational-team-concert

I am using RTC enterprise version 6.0.4.

I am using rtc plain java api to retrieve all changesets for a component using IChangeSetSearchCriteria. Using the same api I can get all changesets in a server If I don't apply the component filter criteria.

I was going through some more investigation and came across this url, which returns all changesets in a server :

**https://server-url:port/ccm/rpt/repository/scm?fields=scm/changeSet/***

So I just wanted to understand RTC on data base level is it possible if somehow a component is deleted and still changesets exist in RTC DB, so when we use above url , it returns list of those changesets too ?

Or Is there any java api (or url as above) which can give me list of all changesets which are not associated any of the component ?